# Cordova Contacts Plugin not always showing Contact List

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have the contacts plugin in my app and on one test device (iPhone 5, iOS 9.02) the contact list does not show. And when I do a search, nothing appears. I get no error messages. On some of my other devices like some Android or iOS 8.x devices it does work. This particular problem device has 1200 contacts. Anyone have some suggestions on how to fix? I'll paste the relevant part of my code. Although maybe it is more of a configuration issue?

```
$scope.getAllContacts = function(searchQuery) {
    try {
        var opts = { //search options
            filter: searchQuery, // 'Bob'
            multiple: true, // Yes, return any contact that matches criteria
            fields: ['displayName', 'name']
        };
        if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
            opts.hasPhoneNumber = true; //hasPhoneNumber only works for android.
        };

        $ionicLoading.show();

        $cordovaContacts.find(opts).then(function(contactsFound) {
            $scope.contacts = contactsFound;
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        });


    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
    }
};

$scope.getAllContacts("Ak");
```

Comment: try commenting the code on `contactsFound` and just put a alert, see if it is coming through. If it is then something taking too much time to process. I had faced the similar situation but on Phonegap where I distributed the process in multiple processes to get the result. BTW I had 5000 contacts

Comment: if the plugin isn't working as expected, file an issue on issues.cordova.io

Answer (score 0):

Hi use this to save all contacts in sdcard and display. (default Cordova contacts and file plugin)

```
     document.addEventListener("deviceReady", deviceReady, false);

  function deviceReady() {

navigator.contacts.find(["*"], function(contacts) {

  //  alert("contacts.length = " + contacts.length);

    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("contacts.json", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                writer.onwriteend = function(){
                  // Success Contacts saved to sdcard as a contacts.json file
                  // Now get and read the json file 

    var path = fileSystem.root.getFile("contacts.json", {create:false},gotFileEntry, fail);

   // jquery

   $.getJSON(path, function (data) {

    user = data;
    $.each(user, function (index, user) {
        var all_item = '<p id="'+user.id+'">'+user.displayName+'</p>';
        $('#allcontacts').append(all_item);
    });
});
                };
                writer.write(JSON.stringify(contacts));

            }, onError);

        }, onError);

    }, onError);

}, onError,{"multiple": true});}  
        function onError(){
            alert("Error"); 
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use  navigator.contacts.find, and see if this works in your phone. 
For more details
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts